# UICollectionView inside UIView Nib

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Problem Statement : I have a UIView Nib. Inside that Nib I have UICollectionView. I created Custom UICollectionViewCell and Assigned its class i.e. ServiceCollectionView Cell. I have 2 labels inside that UICollectionViewCell. Now When I try to Make an Outlet for those labels in custom class, I doesn't let me do that. I Have attached an image too. Anyone have an idea where the problem is ? Or What I am doing wrong. Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Simply create different `Nib` for `CollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Try to restart Xcode, helped me sometimes with the same problem

Comment: You could try to write manually your IBOutlet and then see if you can connect from the interface.
The process you are doing is correct. In case of further problems try to re-create nib after an xcode clean/restart. Something Xcode doesn't manage correctly these type of dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of adding a collection view/ table view in a UIView with separated .xib file, you should also create a separated .xib custom cell.

In your UIView Custom class, you should implement [register(_:​for​Cell​With​Reuse​Identifier:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register), for example:

```
// collectionView is the IBOutlet for the collection view that exists in the view .xib file
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionViewCell")
```

And you will be good to go.

Comment: Bravo! Worked like a Charm! Thanks Man! You saved my 2-3 hours of nonsense :D

Comment: Welcome! glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Xcode opens the interface (yourclass.swift (interface))and not the class. Restart Xcode and switch between automatic and manual did help me.

Answer (score 0):

You create a collection View Cell nib file separately. Now you can give the outlet connection. error is not displayed.